# \times vs. \cdot vs. parentheses vs. nothing while writing fraction multiplications

Tags: notation, article-writing

Is there a convention around writing multiplication of fractions. Let us take two examples to be specific.

#### Example A: $ 2 \times \frac{1}{2} $

Here are some ways to write this example:

- $ 2 \frac{1}{2} $ (does not seem like a good idea because this means $2.5$)
- $ 2 \times \frac{1}{2} $
- $ 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} $
- $ (2) \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) $

#### Example B: $ \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{3}{4} $

Here are some ways to write this example:

- $ \frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{4} $
- $ \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{3}{4} $
- $ \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{4} $
- $ \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) $
- $ \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) $

Is there a preferred way of writing such multiplications in each case?

Comment: In both cases I would bracket the second term and leave the first.

Comment: I personally prefer "$\cdot$" over all of the others. It makes it clear without of the need of say many redundant parentheses,

Answer (score 1):

It’s purely a matter of personal preference, and perhaps of emphasis in context.

For your cases, I would typically use $$2\left(\tfrac12\right)$$ and $$\tfrac12\left(\tfrac34\right),$$
but you are likely to get other answers from other people.

I prefer to omit the multiplication symbol unless that makes the expression appear ambiguous or confusing.

---

**Addendum:**

I point out that you have omitted the “in-line” form $a/b$ which will often require parentheses on its own to avoid ambiguity. For example,
$$\tfrac{x+1}{x-1}$$ is entirely distinct from $$x+1/x-1$$ and I should have written the latter as $$(x+1)/(x-1)$$ if the former were intended.

Comment: I would certainly **never** use "$2\frac{1}{2}$" or "$\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}$".  I would probably tend to use $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)$ or $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)$

Comment: @user247327 : Agreed on the first point: $2\tfrac12$ already has the meaning $2+\tfrac12$ (a mixed fraction) and juxtaposition in this case NEVER indicates multiplication. But I disagree on the second point: $\tfrac12\tfrac34$ is perfectly acceptable and always indicates a product. There is, however, the danger that it might appear as $\tfrac{13}{24}$ if the fraction bars are not clearly separated.

Comment: What happens if we have more than $2$ fractions e.g. $\frac12\frac89\frac34$?

Comment: I would say that $$1\cdot\frac12+\frac12\cdot\frac13+\frac13\cdot\frac14+\ldots$$ looks *imho* more aesthetically pleasing than $$1\left(\frac12\right)+\left(\frac12\right)\left(\frac13\right)+\left(\frac13\right)\left(\frac14\right)+\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

When you only have one kind of multiplication I recommend making it $\cdot$ (or $\times$ if aimed at a young audience,  those who teach team or normal adults), but even then you only need to show it if there's a risk people won't *know* multiplication is intended, e.g. in distinguishing $2+\frac12$ from $2\times\frac12$.

Some kinds of "multiplication" have preferred symbols, such as scalar products on vectors ($\cdot$) or the "cross products" on $3$- or $7$-dimensional vector spaces ($\times$). When that happens, I recommend using whichever of these symbols is unused for a second kind of multiplication you need to discuss, or $\otimes$ (`\otimes`) if you need a third; but if you *do* have multiple operators on the go, make their meaning explicit in the text unless it's *very* standard, e.g. $a\cdot b\times c$ with vectors.

If you have closely related operators, such as the multiplication operations on multiple levels of the Cayley-Dickson construction, you might use subscripts (or hope the reader can disambiguate themselves). For example, the dimension-$2^n$ algebra with multiplication operator $\otimes_n$ gives way to the next viz. $$(p,\,q)\otimes_{n+1}(r,\,s)=(p\otimes_n r-s^\ast\otimes_n q,\,s\otimes_n p+q\otimes_n r^\ast).$$(To my mind $\otimes_n$ works much better for this than $\cdot_n$ or $\times_n$, contra the above advice for cases without subscripts, partly due to kerning issues.) But personally, I think in that case it looks even better to omit the operators, like so: $$(p,\,q)(r,\,s)=(pr-s^\ast q,\,sp+qr^\ast).$$